# Disable jquery asp panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm creating asp.net from to Enable/Disable child Form Elements inside the asp.net panel this script will enable edit form but it will not Disable  it after i click for second time can someone help me ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //createing toggle
        $("#check").button();

        $("[id$='check']").data('isenabled', true); //enabled assumption
        //disabled all input form 
        $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().prop("disabled", "disabled");
        $("input[name='check']").click(function () {
            var curruntState = $(this).data('isenabled');
            if (curruntState) {
                $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().removeProp("disabled");

            }
            else {
                $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().prop("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            $(this).data('isenabled', !currentState);
        }); //EOF click function 
    });//EOF function 
</script>
```

Comment: Please make a note, and not change the code that I have give the answer.

Comment: Ok i just fixed the type of curruntState  to currentState

Answer (score 2):

Your have a bug on the word `currentState`, you have write it `curruntState` elsewhere.

Here is a sample from your code with the correct keyword, that is working fine, (open the console on Google chrome to view the results)

http://jsfiddle.net/zHmh9/4/

Comment: I fix the typo but still will not but I think the problem is on $("[id$=p_taskInfo]").children().prop("disabled", "disabled"); line becouse is not adding prop do you have any idea in how to solve it ?

Comment: @a_Elnajjar Do you have a live version of it ? to see why ? Maybe the children is not found.

Comment: the problem is internal app the network admin block access to dev server

Comment: @a_Elnajjar Can you make a copy/paste version on the jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: this is the link & I'm using asp.net Webform

Comment: @a_Elnajjar To make it work, copy/paste the rendered html code, right click on the page, and select all the html code and the javascript as you have type it. - I found some other issue, I will update the answer

Comment: is mater if i change the clientIDMode to static

Comment: @a_Elnajjar Yes sorry I see that now